# Using replaceWith() + animate / scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to replace a div with another one, but adding an animate effect so while the old div is scrolling to the left, the new one is scrolling from the right of the page?

I mean, if they are simultaneously scrolling on the page, both divs should exist on the page at the same time. However, replaceWith() doesn't let it happen since it removes the old one and appends a new one.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Possible?  Sure!  Next question?

Comment: If you're saying it is possible, HOW is it possible? Any function that I didn't mention? Any piece of code/workaround? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you're talking about `carousel` effect, it's totally NOT about replaceWith.

Comment: How about this: 1) append second one; 2) scroll/animate when 1) ends; 3) remove first one when 2) ends ?

Comment: @Vitor This question is far too broad for SO.

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, I wanted to achieve a carousel effect but I don't want to have all divs loaded at the same time. I'm trying to find a way to achieve the same effect but using replaceWith() or something like that.

Comment: Well, I thought it's quite clear that to show `n + 1` divs at the same time, they have to be in DOM. )

Comment: @Miljan Puzović Sounds good. I just thought there was some jQuery function exactly for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you need both divs in the DOM to do the animation. So there can't be a workaround wich removes one off them from the DOM while letting it still be visible in the animation.